# Only update the SQL fields if the fields are True

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a notification table with the columns id, type, user_id and unseen.

To get new notifications count i use:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM notifications 
WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1
```

To mark only new notifications as seen i use:

```
UPDATE notifications 
SET unseen=0 
WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1
```

But this update query sometimes gives an error. I want to know, what is the right way to do this?

Edit:

> ERROR DESC
>   Transaction (Process ID 68) was deadlocked on lock; communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: What do you mean with "*this update query sometimes gives an error*"? Which error?

Comment: This will update all the notifications of a user unseen to false. You should mention some notification unique code so that only the required one will get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be issue of deadlock, while you are trying to update the records, some is also reading those records.

Your update statement is a complete statement, i think it is not running in a transaction. It seems, you want more priority to complete the updated statement instead of read statment (using select).

For above mentioned scenario, you can allow phantom read (every time user use executes the select query gets different output) by using NoLock while reading. In your scenario, it will be not a dirty read because you will be reading only commited records.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM notifications (NOLOCK) WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1
```

Comment: Actualy these two query cause deadlock.
>SELECT TOP 20 * FROM notifications WHERE user_id = 123 ORDER BY notice_id DESC and UPDATE notifications SET unseen=0 WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1

Comment: In your scenario, just go with NOLOCK while reading the record. SELECT TOP 20 * FROM notifications (NOLOCK) WHERE user_id = 123 ORDER BY notice_id DESC

Answer (score 0):

Following statement will ignore the locked records and uncommited records.

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM notifications WITH(READPAST)  
WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1
```

Following statement will lock the records which need to update, it will not lock the whole table.

```
UPDATE notifications  with (ROWLOCK) 
SET unseen=0 
WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1
```

So using READPAST and ROWLOCK hint, you can avoid the deadlock.

[Read from her to know about READPAST and NOLOCK](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints-in-sql-server/6185492)

Answer (score -1):

In "Update" you should to mark the record that you seen with some thing like Primery key of the record.

```
UPDATE notifications SET unseen=0 WHERE user_id=123 AND unseen=1 and PKID='some thing'
```

Comment: While that may be true in some situations, it's not true in all.  Also, what the poster has submitted is valid SQL, and so should not cause an error.